# Making a Tree-Like Structure in VisualForce/Apex from a Self-Referencing Table/sObject

Tags: tree, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

My Controllers are all custom.

I have an object/table with a field that references the same object and signifies the parent object.

There are many rows in the object/table.

I wish to dump all of them to the VF and allow users to check off which rows are applicable to them. If a parent object is not applicable to a user, the child object will never be.

To limit how many items the user has to see on the page, I wish to display only the top-level objects, and only if the user selects a top level object will he see its child objects. Top level objects could theoretically have unlimited depth.

How is this best accomplished in VisualForce and Apex?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To display for example only Parent Accounts all you need is

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE ParentId = null
```

When your user decides he wants to view children of one record (which could be done as `<apex:actionFunction>` on the checkbox for example) you will be able to query up to 5 + 1 levels deep. Start with this query and experiment

```
SELECT Id, Name, (optional subquery here)
FROM Account
WHERE ParentId = :selectedId
    OR Parent.ParentId = :selectedId
    OR Parent.Parent.ParentId = :selectedId
    ... // We can use up to 5 dots
ORDER BY ParentId, Parent.ParentId, Parent.Parent.ParentId ...
```

By 5+1 I mean 5 "dots" and an option for subquery. It will not work on Accounts but on your custom object you should be able to put `(SELECT Id FROM CustomObjects__r)` there as well.

Then you'll have to somehow display them nicely in a tree ;) There are lots of Javascript tools that accept hierarchical JSON data or you might decide to build lots of nested `<apex:repeat>`... Just watch out for hitting viewstate limits!

Check these links for some inspiration / caveats:

1. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4537/how-to-reduce-a-large-internal-view-state-what-is-in-the-internal-view-state
2. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016chCEAQ (free)
3. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001gFEWEA2 (paid, no idea if there's a "trial run" option you could use to view at least the Visualforce used. *I'm not related to this Company in any way*)